# Print dom when selenium misses an element I see

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**How to find what selenium see in a dom where it misses an image I see on screen?**

*Context:* I have a Selenium python test

```python
browser.wait_to_find_visible_element(By.ID, 'image')
```

that sometimes can't find an image that I see on the browser selenium launched for the test:

```html
<div id="container">
    <img id='image' src=''/>
</div>
```

To find out what selenium see instead, I get the enclosing `div`:

```python
element  = browser.find_displayed_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#container')
print element
```

which prints:

> selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x9b3876c

and try to get the dom:

```python
dom = browser.driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].parentNode', element)
print dom
```

which prints

```
None
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: What `return arguments[0].parentNode` is used for ?

Comment: @e1che: `arguments[0].parentNode` is used only to get the dom from the enclosing element

Comment: Did you try to do a `print element.getAttribute("id")` to be sure that you have the `container`??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
element  = browser.find_displayed_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#container')
source_code = element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
# or
source_code = element.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```